# How to set name to instance of ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to set name to each instance of the ThreadLocal variable of type WebDriver. And then get the ThreadLocal instance by name. Is there a way to set and get ThreadLocal instance by name?

Here is my class where I want to add the set and get functions.

```
public class DFactory {
    private DFactory() {

    }

    private static DFactory dInstance= new DFactory();

    public static DFactory getInstance() {
        return dInstance;
    }

    ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver.get();
    }

    public void setDriver(WebDriver driverParam) {
        driver.set(driverParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: ...name of what?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you want to do. Exactly what does "get the ThreadLocal instance by name" mean? Please edit your question and explain.

Comment: I need to set the name to the instance of ThreadLocal similar to what we do to Thread by using Thread.setName() and Thread.getName().

Comment: Looking at your example, I can't understand why you need a name.  Please show us the code that illustrates why the `ThreadLocal` "needs" a name ... and we can (maybe) suggest an alternative that is actually going to be viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to set and get ThreadLocal instance by name?

No, there isn't a way.

`ThreadLocal` variables don't have names, and cannot be accessed by name.  That is not part of the `ThreadLocal` API.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here, but one possibility is to create a `ThreadLocal` whose type is `Map<String, Object>` and store your "named" variables in the maps.

Comment: My purpose is to create Thread-safe WebDriver instances and access it by it's name. I know we can setName and getName to the instances of Thread class in Java by using Thread.setName() and Thread.getName(). I want to do same thing by using ThreadLocal.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that you can't do that.  Look for a different way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Stephen C! Your suggestion of using Map<String, Object>  worked like a charm.